# Cross thread operation not valid in BackgroundWorker

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, backgroundworker

I want to display some data on form load in a data gridview , the data which i           want to display is in large number of rows , when i use background worker processor it show me the following error.

My code:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        FTPUtility obj = new FTPUtility();
        dataGridViewRequest.DataSource = obj.ListRequestFiles();
        dataGridViewRequest.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewRequest.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewRequest.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

        dataGridViewResponses.DataSource = obj.ListResponseFiles();
        dataGridViewResponses.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewResponses.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridViewResponses.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Form load:

```
private void FormFTP_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        //this.comboBoxRequests.SelectedIndex = 0;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are doing (= trying to modify a GUI element from the `BackgroundWorker` thread) cannot be done. You should better read something about `BackgroundWorker`/multithreading in C#/.NET because your ideas are quite unclear.

Comment: @varocarbas i am trying to fetch files from ftp on my local windows application datagridview , when i am loading the data it take too much time , so i want to first load main form and then after some second the files display in datagridview.

Comment: As explained in my previous comment: your code is doing something which proves you absolute lack of knowledge regarding `BackgroundWorker` and the underlying ideas (i.e., multithreading). Improve your knowledge on both fronts, rather than doing blind tests and complaining about each single problem you see.

Comment: @varocarbas i solve problem thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways to prevent the form from being freezed.
For example you can load your data like this:

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do some initializations
    await LoadData();
    //do some other initializations that you need to perform.
}

private async Task LoadData()
{
    //Load your data here
    //For example
    FTPUtility obj = new FTPUtility();
    dataGridViewRequest.DataSource = obj.ListRequestFiles();
}
```

This way when running the form, the commands run in the sequence you wrote while the UI is responsive and you will not face with common difficulties of using `BackgroundWorker` or threads like Cross thread operation exceptions.

The key point is in using async/await. For more information read [Asynchronous Programming with Async and Await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Remember that this way, every where you want to call LoadData, you should call it this way:

```
await LoadData();
```

And the method that you write this code in, should be async:

```
private async void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await LoadData();
}
```

**EDIT For .Net 4.0**

---

For .Net 4.0 you can use both `Task.Run` or `BackgroundWorker`. I recommend `Task.Run` because it is more simple and more readable.

Please note Cross Thread Operation Exception will throw when you access the UI elements from another thread than UI. In this situations you should use `this.Invoke(new Action(()=>{/*Access UI Here*/}));` instead. And never put a time-consuming task in your invoke part.

**BackgroundWorker Approach:**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    //If you put some code here for example MessageBox.Show(""); 
    //The code will immadiately run and don't wait for worker to complete the task.
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.LoadData();
}

public void LoadData()
{
    var ftp = new FtpUtility();
    var data = ftp.ListRequestFiles();
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //Setup columns and other UI stuff
        //Set datasource of grid
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }));
}
```

- Remember everywhere you formerly used `LoadData`, now you should use `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` instead.
- If you want to do a job after the worker completes the task, put your job in `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` or in `Invoke` part of `LoadData`.

**Task.Run Approach**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        LoadData();
    })
    .ContinueWith(x =>
    {
        //You can put codes you want run after LoadData completed here
        //If you access the UI here, you should use Invoke
    });
    //If you put some code here for example MessageBox.Show(""); 
    //The code will immadiately run and don't wait for worker to complete the task.
}

public void LoadData()
{
    var ftp = new FtpUtility();
    var data = ftp.ListRequestFiles();
    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //Setup columns and other UI stuff
        //Set datasource of grid
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    }));
}
```

- Remember everywhere you formerly used `LoadData`, now you should use `Task.Run(()=>{LoadData();});` instead.
- If you want to do a job after the `LoadData` completes, put your job in `ContinueWith` or in `Invoke` part of `LoadData`.

Comment: private async its give an error , are you missing a namespace.

Comment: @RazimKhan It works for .Net 4.5 and it seems you are working with .Net 4.0 so, I will update the code for .Net 4.0

Comment: @RazimKhan I edited the answer and offered 2 way, hope you find it helpful:)

Comment: @RazimKhan, I think this answer would be helpful for future readers. What solution you used at last?

Comment: @RazimKhan Good job, and what did you do for problem of freezing UI?

Comment: myTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(myTimer_Tick);

Comment: @RazimKhan When you perform a time-consuming operation there, the UI will be freezed and for example you can not click on any controls or even move form. In such cases you can use the `Task.Run` approach that I described here :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei task run  not working in my case. form still freeze until the datagridview loaded. i use bindingsource.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

       dataGridViewRequest.Invoke(new Action(() => {
            FTPUtility obj = new FTPUtility();
            dataGridViewRequest.DataSource = obj.ListRequestFiles();
            dataGridViewRequest.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridViewRequest.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridViewRequest.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

            dataGridViewResponses.DataSource = obj.ListResponseFiles();
            dataGridViewResponses.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridViewResponses.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            dataGridViewResponses.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
       }));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}

private void FormFTP_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        //this.comboBoxRequests.SelectedIndex = 0;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never try that ;) you are putting the time-consuming task in `Invoke` that it means it will run in UI thread and it will freeze UI again.  Instead you should run time-consuming task first, then in invoke part, only access UI and set UI properties, in this example `obj.ListRequestFiles();` should be called before invoke and never in invoke part. To test it yourselft, it is enough to use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` instead of that  `obj.ListRequestFiles();` to see the result.

Comment: It won't freeze the UI because your using the backgroundworker :)

Comment: Common mistake about `BackgroundWorker`, yes it runs on a different thread but when you use `Invoke` the code in action that passed to invoke will be run in UI thread and since you are putting the main time-consuming an freezing line of code in that action, the UI will be freezed. To test it yourselft, it is enough to use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` instead of that `obj.ListRequestFiles();` to see the result.