# Progressbar freezes in winform

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, progress-bar

I am trying to process a file which contains 10,000+ lines and store it in database. Processing a file usually takes 2-3 minutes, so I want to display the `progressbar`.

Problem with the program is that I `progressbar` control as well as `label` which is in `processForm` doesn't display at all. I've googled for hours, but still I haven't been able to solve it.

[image]

Here is my code
`btnApplyEOD_Click` method which processes the file

```
private void btnApplyEOD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = txtEODReport.Text;
    if (url != null)
    {
        using (var file = new System.IO.StreamReader(url))
        {
            int i = 0;
            linesInEOD = File.ReadAllLines(url).Count();

            if (backgroundWorkerEOD.IsBusy != true)
            {
                progressForm = new ProgressForm();
                progressForm.Show();
                backgroundWorkerEOD.RunWorkerAsync();
            }

            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splitLines = line.Split('~');
                switch (splitLines[0])
                {
                    case "01":
                    {
                        BOID = splitLines[1].Trim() + splitLines[2].Trim();
                        break;
                    }
                    .........
                }
                i++;
                currentLine = i;
            }
        }
        ...........
        bindToGridView();
    }

}
```

I've used `BackgroundWorker` and code for `BackgroundWorker_DoWork` method is as following:

```
private void backgroundWorkerEOD_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker workerEOD = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    //for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)             //usually works but useless for this scenario
    //{
    //    workerEOD.ReportProgress(i * 10);
    //    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    //}

    for (int i = 1; i <= linesInEOD; i++)       // doesn't work at all but it will give accurate progressbar increase 
    {
        workerEOD.ReportProgress(100 * currentLine / linesInEOD);
    }
}
```

`BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged` method:

```
private void backgroundWorkerEOD_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    progressForm.Message = "In progress, please wait... " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
    progressForm.ProgressValue = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Comment: You should move your processing inside the `DoWork` method. Currently your background worker is doing nothing, because all the processing is on the UI thread.

Comment: @IvanStoev : Yep, that was the problem. thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are performing your time-consuming task in UI thread, so freezing UI is normal. I think you should put your time-consuming task in `DoWork` of `BackgroundWorker` and call `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` when you need:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    this.PerformTimeConsumingTask();
}

public void PerformTimeConsumingTask()
{
    //Time-Consuming Task

    //When you need to update UI
    progressForm.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        progressForm.ProgressValue = someValue;
    }));
}
```

If you are using .Net 4.5 you can also consider using [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) pattern.

Comment: I did it in the wrong way, rather than assigning the processing task to  `backgroundWorkerEOD_DoWork`, I assigned the progressbar task to `DoWork`. This is my first time in `WinForms` and `progressbar`, so I didn't had a clue what I was doing wrong. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Comment: You are welcome:) you may find my description [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32620833/3110834) helpful too.